# Is there sql WITH clause equivalent in hive?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

Failed to find the answer in the specs.

So, I wonder: Can I do something like that in hive?

```
insert into table my_table
with a as
(
    select *
        from ...
        where ...  
),

b as
(
    select *
        from ...
        where ...  
)
select 
    a.a, 
    a.b, 
    a.c, 
    b.a, 
    b.b, 
    b.c 
from a join b on (a.a=b.a);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With is available in Hive as of version `0.13.0`. [Usage documented here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select).

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could always use subqueries:

```
insert into table my_table
select 
    a.a, 
    a.b, 
    a.c, 
    b.a, 
    b.b, 
    b.c 
from
(
    select *
        from ...
        where ...  
) a
join 
(
    select *
        from ...
        where ...  
) b
on a.a = b.a;
```

Answer (score 2):

[*Hadoop Hive WITH Clause Syntax and Examples*](https://dwgeek.com/hadoop-hive-with-clause-syntax-examples.html/)
*With the Help of Hive WITH clause you can reuse piece of query result in same query construct. You can also improve the Hadoop Hive query using `WITH` clause. You can simplify the query by moving complex, complicated repetitive code to the WITH clause and refer the logical table created in your SELECT statements.*

---

***Hive WITH clause example with the SELECT statement***

```
WITH t1 as (SELECT 1), 
t2 as (SELECT 2),
t3 as (SELECT 3)
SELECT * from t1 
UNION ALL
SELECT * from t2
UNION ALL 
SELECT * from t3;
```

***Hive WITH Clause in INSERT Statements***
You can use the WITH clause while inserting data to table. For example:

```
WITH t11 as (SELECT 10),
t12 as (SELECT 20),
t13 as (SELECT 3) 
INSERT INTO t1 
SELECT * from t11 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * from t12 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * from t13;
```